# Update operation is not working properly in jsp/servlet/mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jsp, servlets

I'm new to the java web application developing. I have done insert, read, delete operations myself but following update operation not working.I didn't identify any error but update data is not going to mysql database. please let me know your suggestions.I didn't add the jsp part for you because inserting data working fine , I used the same jsp for the update form also.

### AdminServiceImpl.java

```
package service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary.Base64;

import model.AdminLogin;
import model.AdminProduct;
import util.DBConnection;

public class AdminServiceImpl implements IAdminService{

//Item update method 
    public void UpdateItemValues(AdminProduct admin) {


        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;


        con = DBConnection.connect();


        try {

            String query = "update NewJewelry set Jname=?,Jcatogorie=?,Jquantity=?,Jsetting=?,JmetalW=?,JstoneW=?,Jdescription=?,Jprice=?,image=? where JID=?";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

            ps.setString(1, admin.getProductName());
            ps.setString(2, admin.getProductCat());
            ps.setInt(3,admin.getQuantity());
            ps.setString(4, admin.getSettingWith());
            ps.setString(5, admin.getMetalWeight());
            ps.setString(6, admin.getStoneWeight());
            ps.setString(7, admin.getDescription());
            ps.setDouble(8, admin.getPrice());

            try {
                InputStream is = admin.getImage().getInputStream();
                ps.setBlob(9, is);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                 //TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ps.setInt(10,admin.getPID());

            ps.executeUpdate();


        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

### AdminUpdateProductServlet.java

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import model.AdminProduct;
import service.AdminServiceImpl;
import service.IAdminService;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class AdminAddProductServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/AdminUpdateProductServlet")
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177216)

public class AdminUpdateProductServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public AdminUpdateProductServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        AdminProduct product = new AdminProduct();

        product.setProductName(request.getParameter("product_name"));
        product.setProductCat(request.getParameter("product_categorie"));
        product.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("available_quantity")));
        product.setSettingWith(request.getParameter("setting_with"));
        product.setMetalWeight(request.getParameter("metal_weight"));
        product.setStoneWeight(request.getParameter("stone_weight"));
        product.setDescription(request.getParameter("product_description"));
        product.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("product_price")));
        product.setImage(request.getPart("filebutton"));

        IAdminService iAdminService = new AdminServiceImpl();
        iAdminService.UpdateItemValues(product);

        response.sendRedirect("admin/product-report.jsp");

    }

}
```

Mysql query:

```
create table NewJewelry
(
    JID int not null auto_increment,
    Jname varchar(50),
    Jcatogorie varchar(50),
    Jquantity int,
    Jsetting varchar(50),
    JmetalW varchar(50),
    JstoneW varchar(50),
    Jdescription varchar(1000),
    Jprice double,
    image longblob,
    primary key (JID))auto_increment = 1000;
)
```

Comment: `JID` is a Blob?!?? Oh no, it's an `int`. Wow, that duplicate `setBlob(9, is)` and `setInt(9,admin.getPID())` sure confused me.

Comment: oh i'm sorry that is a mistake when i copy the code from old copy that i've edited first.it is setInt(10,admin.getPID()) in my new code.but still it is not working.

Comment: did you got any error?

Comment: @Swati no there is no error.i have already created working(CRUD) web app using this same code but i modified that code like this to update blob type image.I didn't find any error while project run on the server.but once i saw "Illegal access" error on the console but that one is also gone.I'm stucked here for few weeks plz help me, this is my final project  i need to fix this soon for further develop.thank you.

Comment: Okay so problem is in image update? Everthing else works without image i. e does after removing image from update query does data gets updated in table ?

Comment: @Swati yes it worked without image update in previous project.i checked the project without image update quary and codes but still same,no value is updated.however data insertion is working properly.

Comment: Where did you set value for `JID` ,also what does this `admin.getPID()` have in it ,try to print and see .

Comment: oh my god thank you a lot my friend you saved my time. how do i rate you. i'm new to stackoverflow.. error is because of missing this part, thank you for your time friend`product.setPID(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("product_id")));`